# Independence of Brownian motions

Tags: brownian-motion, independence

Let $W_t$ be a Brownian motion at time $t$ and let $t<t_1<T$. I'm trying to find the variance of
$$ k\sigma W_{t_1} + \sigma \left(W_T - W_t\right).$$
I started by letting
$$ k\sigma W_{t_1} + \sigma \left(W_T - W_t\right) = k\sigma W_{t_1} + \sigma \left(W_T - W_t\right) -\sigma W_{t_1} + \sigma W_{t_1},$$
which I expressed as
$$ k\sigma W_{t_1} + \sigma \left(W_T-W_{t_1}\right) + \sigma \left(W_{t_1}-W_t \right).$$

I know that $W_T-W_{t_1}$ and $W_{t_1}-W_t$ are independent.

Can I use this property to find the variance as
$k^2\sigma^2 t_1+ \sigma^2\left(T-t\right)?$

Comment: I fail to see where your decomposition is going, try rather to write your random variable as $a(W_T-W_{t_1})+b(W_{t_1}-W_t)+cW_t$ for some suitable $(a,b,c)$ and then use independence to deduce that the variance is $a^2(T-t_1)+b^2(t_1-t)+c^2t$.

Comment: That's what I did above, except that I have the term $ k\sigma W_{t_1}$ instead of $cW_t$. Do I proceed in the same way as you mentioned?

Comment: You arrived at the blocks $W_{t_1}$, $W_T-W_{t_1}$ and $W_{t_1}-W_t$, that are not independent. The decomposition I suggest, which directly leads to the result, uses the independent blocks $W_T-W_{t_1}$, $W_{t_1}-W_t$, and $W_t$.

Comment: Okay, I get it. In the case where $t_1<t$, I can use the decomposition that I reached.

Comment: No, one cannot, not even then.